# How to control async textbox event

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a textbox where its Leave event is like this:

```
private async void TxtLotTextLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isChecked)
    {
        isChecked = true;
        var mylength = BarcodeUtil.LotStripZeroes(txtLot.Text.Trim()).Length;
        var strippedLot = BarcodeUtil.LotStripZeroes(txtLot.Text.Trim());
        if (mylength > 0)
        {
            if (mylength.Between(16, 18) &&
                (strippedLot.StartsWith(AppState.LotOldStandardDigits) ||
                 strippedLot.StartsWith(AppState.LotStandardDigits)))
            {
                await GetLotData();
            }
            else
            {
                ShowAppMessage(AppMessages["WrongLot"], 0, Color.Black, Color.BlanchedAlmond);
                txtLot.Text = "";
                LotFocus(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

99% of the time i need this event to work like this.

**BUT i only need when a specific button is clicking NOT to fire it.**

Button click:

```
private void BtnClearClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearForm();
    LotFocus(true);
}
```

I tried the obvious to use a global bool variable and set it to false in click event and check it in leave but it doesnt work..I suspect that has to do with async?

**Additional Info:**

What i tried is to create a bool variable `needTxtValidation` and try to set it to false in various places like button click, textbox keypress, button mousedown, but it didnt work.

Comment: Post your attempt with the boolean flag, that should work. And AFAIK there is no clean way to do what you're trying to achieve. Also, which UI framework? Winforms or..?

Comment: I could use a dirty one too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's the dirty way I managed to find. You need to inherit the `Button`, override the `WndProc` and expose a boolean which says whether currently processing `MouseDown`.

```
class ButtonEx : Button
{
    public bool IsInMouseDown { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        try
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
                IsInMouseDown = true;
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        finally //Make sure we set the flag to false whatever happens.
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)//Required to fight with reentracy
                IsInMouseDown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your leave method

```
private async void TxtLotTextLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourButton.IsInMouseDown)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ignoring Leave");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

This works, however I won't guarantee it will continue to work always. You may need to address some corner cases or obvious thing which I've missed. That's a very hacky code, you are better off re-designing the logic.